# Writing to a txt file without clearing the previous content

Tags: java, file

I want to know how do I write a line to a file without clearing or flushing it. What classes and packages do I need?
I've tried with FileOutputStream and PrintStream (using println) and with BufferedWriter and OutputStreamWriter (using write) but they erase the previous content from the file.

```
try
    {
        File txt = new File("marcos.txt");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        writer.write(registro);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();    

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error en la escritura al archivo.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method writeStringToFile under the class FileUtils from org.apache.commons.io

public static void writeStringToFile(File file,
                     String data,
                     Charset encoding,
                     boolean append)
                              throws IOException
Writes a String to a file creating the file if it does not exist.
Parameters:
file - the file to write
data - the content to write to the file
encoding - the encoding to use, null means platform default
append - if true, then the String will be added to the end of the file rather than overwriting
Throws:
IOException - in case of an I/O error